# Comparing two arraylists unequal sizes - heap issue post comparison

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am comparing two `arraylist<String>` with average size of list one, `50K`, and List two, `200K`.

```
int size = MsSQLList.size();

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    if (!oracleSQLList.contains(MsSQLList.get(index))) {                        
        logger.debug(" *[POSSIBLE MISS]* Oracle missing record id: "
                       + (MsSQLList.get(index)));
    }
}
```

The list have data in String as 16 chararcters, i.e. A89EERDD12312445 etc... I am running a `Collection.sort(list)` on both before entering the above loop.

The average comparison times are close to 160 seconds. Is this the best approach or can we do this much better?

Question 2:
The results as you have guessed are being fetched  from DB,  for a 5 day interval.

Ideally I can get 1.1 million records if I choose 30 days as my interval.  Old array list implementation was throwing OutofMemory due to this load.

So a quick follow up question is can I now push the load back to 1.1 million ,30 day interval  ?

Comment: use hash maps instead of arrays and sorting

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean ?.

Comment: A HashSet would make more sense than a map. That operation shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: Can you elaborate either approach,
thanks

Comment: @VR: about `HashSet`: Fill the Set with the content of the first list and then loop over the second list and do `if (set.add(itemSecondList)) { .. "POSSIBLE MISS" .. }`. The `add` method of `Set` returns `true` if the element was added successfully (element wasn't in the list before) or `false` if the `Set` already contains the element. Therefore it does the `contains` check for you and this in the much faster way than of the `List` implementation of `contains`.

Comment: Thanks Tom this approach does the job wonderfully.
Lesson learnt :)

Comment: The anlysis now takes 10-12 seconds that a huge improvement Hurray !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that `contains()` is O(n), because it simply iterates through the list until it gets a hit (average iterations is n/2), which of course performs poorly.

Also, sorting the list does nothing useful for performance.

The humble `HashSet` is your friend: It has O(1) performance of all operations.

Using a set also lets you do it all in a few lines:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(oracleSQLList);
for (String s : MsSQLList)
    if (!set.contains(s))                  
        logger.debug(" *[POSSIBLE MISS]* Oracle missing record id: " + s);
```

The above code should complete in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are unique, put them in `Set`s rather than Array Lists.

Suppose you have

```
Set<String> oracleSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> msSet = new HashSet<>();
```

Then after you fill them up, You can use

```
msSet.removeAll(oracleList);
```

Then, if `msSet.isEmpty()` returns `false`, you know you have items in `msSet` which did not exist in `oracleSet`. And you can print them all if you wish by iterating on `msSet`.

Of course, if you need to keep `msSet` for further work as it was before the deletion, use a copy of it:

```
Set<String> copyOfMsSet = new HashSet<>( msSet );
```

and use `copyOfMsSet.removeAll(oracleList)` instead of `msSet.removeAll(oracleList)`.

`HashSet`s are very efficient to search, if you don't need the items to be ordered. If you do, you should probably use a `TreeSet`, but that will be less efficient. Mind you, the efficiency depends on the set's capacity and load factor (which can be set in the constructor) and this may affect performance for very large sets.

If the `oracleSet` is much larger than the `msSet`, it may by more efficient to do something like this:

```
Set <String> intersectionOfMsAndOracleSets = new HashSet<>( msSet );
intersectionOfMsAndOracleSets.retainAll( oracleSet );
```

And then

```
msSet.removeAll( intersectionOfMsAndOracleSets );
```

That is, suppose `msSet` has a size of `n` and `oracleSet` has a size of `m`, and `n` is much smaller than `m`, then the operation of the intersection takes O(n), while my original suggestion is O(m). If `m` is about four times bigger than `n`, this becomes more efficient.

Comment: It is reasonable to assume that the oracle list is larger than the ms list, otherwise there would be lots of misses. If so, although convenient to call `removeAll()`, there are negative performance implications to doing so, because logically there will be many pointless calls to remove items not in the set.

Comment: yes the oracle list has much more records,  Records in both lists are always Unique.   Moving them to set did solve the issue

Comment: I added a little suggestion for the case when the disparity between the sets is very big.

Answer (score 1):

as you have yours list sorted, you can do instead quadratic complexity, you could use linear approach

```
for (int i=0,j=0;i<MsSQLList.size();i++){
            if (j>=oracleSQLList.size() || !MsSQLList.get(i).equals(oracleSQLList.get(j))){
                 logger.debug(" *[POSSIBLE MISS]* Oracle missing record id: "
                   + (MsSQLList.get(index)));
            }else{
                j++;
            }

        }
```

but again, your bottleneck here will be sorting, unless you will be able do this in database

Comment: or even better [`Collections.binarySearch(List, element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)

Comment: @zapl  to use `binarySearch` you will have one loop anyway,as you need call search on any item from list `a` on list `b`. So if you have your array sorted for free, binarysearch has complexity `O(n*log(m))` . my solution as it's linear it has complexity `O(n)`

Comment: Oops, I see what you're saying. I was thinking about just 1 sorted list :) Your code is IMO bugged though: there needs to be something that compares elements from list 1 and 2 to decide whether to advance i or j per iteration. something like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b1a723d4117ed89d9b3b or you would afaik skip elements.

Comment: @zapl you are right, i assume second list is nnot complete copy of first one, but its easy fix